# Android simple cursor for 2 field into 1 label

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I get some data from a `database` and I show it into a `listview`, with a `SimpleCursosAdapter` whit this code:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(App.getAppContext(),R.layout.list_view_row,c,
                new String[] { "titolo_testo","titolo_sezione","text" },
                new int[] { R.id.label_testo , R.id.label_materia , R.id.label_testo }, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
```

what I want is to add a field:

```
new String[] { "titolo_testo","titolo_sezione","titolo_materia","text" }
```

and put

`"titolo_sezione","titolo_materia"` into the same label `R.id.label_materia`

which is the best way for do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be don't use SimpleCursorAdapter and extend CursorAdapter. Here is an example:

http://www.gustekdev.com/2013/05/custom-cursoradapter-and-why-not-use.html

Answer (score 1):

For use this approach you can create your `custom Adapter` and then use it.